# iPhone: What is `accountsd` and why is it using 80% CPU?

Tags: iphone, battery, cpu

I just got a new iPhone 6 for my SO and noticed that it is quite toasty to handle with the battery draining quite fast.  It has been 24 hours since I first set it up.  I plugged it into Instruments and loaded the Activity Monitor and noticed that `accountsd` is chewing through 80% of the CPU:

[image]

**What is `accountsd` on iOS and why is it chewing up so much CPU?**

Comment: It might be trying to gain access to the keychain on iCloud. Means the keychain needs to be repaired.

Comment: @Buscar웃 A restart seems to have resolved the issue, but I am still curious what `accountsd` does on iOS.

Comment: It syncs accounts and managed them and their secrets (credentials). Most commonly AppleID and email accounts, but also instant messaging and social networks.

Answer (score 1):

Accountsd and cloudd manage iCloud. There's an insanely annoying bug which lots of people have where a sign into icloud password prompt comes up every few seconds and you can't sign out of find my phone.